# What is the meaning of const {data}=await axios.post? Does it looking for login data we sent?

Tags: javascript, arrays, destructuring

For register user
`const response= await axios.post()`
But for login user
`Const {data} = await axios.post()`

What is the need of **{data}**?

Answer (score 1):

It extract the key data from the object that axios.post() returns.
https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-object-destructuring/

Answer (score 0):

This is called [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

If you look into the [axios response schema](https://axios-http.com/docs/res_schema), you will see it has a key by name `data` which contains the response from the server. So destructuring the axios response will take the `data` from the axios response and will assign to `data` variable
`const {data} = await axios.post()`

For example if you do `const {data,status} = await axios.post()` it will assign the status from the axios response into the `status` variable.

```js
{
  // `data` is the response that was provided by the server
  data: {},

  // `status` is the HTTP status code from the server response
  status: 200,

  // `statusText` is the HTTP status message from the server response
  // As of HTTP/2 status text is blank or unsupported.
  // (HTTP/2 RFC: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-8.1.2.4)
  statusText: 'OK',

  // `headers` the HTTP headers that the server responded with
  // All header names are lower cased and can be accessed using the bracket notation.
  // Example: `response.headers['content-type']`
  headers: {},

  // `config` is the config that was provided to `axios` for the request
  config: {},

  // `request` is the request that generated this response
  // It is the last ClientRequest instance in node.js (in redirects)
  // and an XMLHttpRequest instance in the browser
  request: {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is "object destructuring".

You just get the object property called "data".

When you call axios, there is an object returned, and instead of doing

```
const login = axios.post()
const data = login.data
```

You're directly accessing the data property.